# How to perform batch update in Sql through C# code

Tags: c#, sql

I want to update multiple rows like below

```
update mytable set s_id = {0} where id = {1}
```

(Here `s_id` is evaluated based on some complex logic).
For performance reason, updates should happen in batches. Is there any way to batch the update statements and execute the batch through single execute statements? I know in JAVA we can do this through JDBC. Is there similar way in C#?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can use an [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx).

The SqlDataAdapter has [InsertCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355223.aspx) and [UpdateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341370.aspx) properties which allow you to specify an SQLCommand to use to insert new rows into the database and an SqlCommand to update rows in the database respectively.

You can then pass a DataTable to the [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update.aspx) method of the dataadapter, and it will batch up the statements to the server - for rows in the DataTable that are new rows, it executes the INSERT command, for modified rows it executes the UPDATE command.

You can define the batch size using the [UpdateBatchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xw5z0hdd.aspx) property.

This approach allows you to deal with large volumes of data, and allows you to nicely handle errors in different ways, i.e. if an error is encountered with a particular update, you can tell it to NOT throw an exception but to carry on with the remaining updates by setting the [ContinueUpdateOnError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.continueupdateonerror.aspx) property.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can build a plain-text SQL command (parameterized for security), like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
// Set connection, etc.
for(int i=0; i< items.length; i++) {
    command.CommandText += string.Format("update mytable set s_id=@s_id{0} where id = @id{0};", i);
    command.Parameters.Add("@s_id" + i, items[i].SId);
    command.Parameters.Add("@id" + i, items[i].Id);
}
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I like this approach. Much easier to implement/debug than SqlDataAdapter for my purposes.

Comment: @Arvand How do you address this?

Comment: @Arvayne Depends on what you are doing, but transactions usually are a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

Use a StringBuilder (System.Text.StringBuilder) to build your Sql, such as:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
int batchSize = 10;
int currentBatchCount = 0;
SqlCommand cmd = null; // The SqlCommand object to use for executing the sql.
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfUpdatesToMake; i++)
{
  int sid = 0; // Set the s_id here
  int id = 0; // Set id here
  sql.AppendFormat("update mytable set s_id = {0} where id = {1}; ", sid, id);

  currentBatchCount++;
  if (currentBatchCount >= batchSize)
  {
    cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql = new StringBuilder();
    currentBatchCount = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably because SQL Injection attacks are possible with your code

Comment: Not if its just integer values

Comment: @GvS SQL Injection is not relevant when there is no untrusted input. Anyone with the ability to change `int id = 0` could just as easily change the whole query.

Comment: Not really a SQL Injection issue in this case, but a bad practice. Use Parameters for security.

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of those updates (with the id's filled in), separate them by semicolon in one string, set the resulting string to a SqlCommand's CommandText property, then call ExecuteNonQuery().